# Add a view layout to a new tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-view

In my app, I allow the user to create new tabs. The tab creates fine, but I do not know how I would be able to add an already created layout to that new tab.

I have tried `setContent(R.layout.layout_browse)` but that causes a force close, as does adding a view to the factory and returning it.

So, how can I do what I am after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

```
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.yourxmllayout,
                    null);
            parent.addView(view );
```